# AngularJS - ng-app

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS app. I notice that there is a directive called `ng-app`. I'm trying to understand how Angular is loads. For that reason, I'm looking for where `ng-app` is actually defined in the [AngularJS repository on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js). However, I have been unable to find where `ng-app` is defined.

Can somebody please tell me where `ng-app` is defined?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1279

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation rather than dive in the code? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp. And why don't you look for it in the built angular.js file that you download and which contains the whole thing?